# SonarQube - cannot do Restore Profile

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to import a quality profile that is in xml-format. My SonarQube runs fine with the quality profile that is in jar-format, but it does not import the xml whatsoever.

It is not just one xml that is causing the problem. When I back up a working quality profile (originated in jar-format) and restore it, it causes a similar problem.

SonarQube version: 4.3.1 
DB: psql
OS: red hat

Steps taken:

1. Downloaded xml created from other computer (I believe it was made in red hat linux as well)
2. Log in as admin. Go to Quality Profiles -> Restore Profile -> selected xml back up profile.
3. Error message show up:

> - Rule not found: [repository=c-cppcheck, key=selfAssignment]
> - Rule not found: [repository=c-cppcheck, key=returnTempPointer] ....

Other things I tried:

1. Download opensource quality profile. Back them up and it create xml. Using xml backup file to restore. result is same "Rule not found" message
2. Even tried using curl to upload profile but it gave me a similar errors. 
   It actually gave more than just 4 error message. They were all about Rule not found.
3. Tried to remove SonarQube and install. Same.
4. Dropped db and recreated to see if that makes any change. Same.

SonarQube Doc. says it is possible. I am not sure what I am doing it wrong.

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Profile+Existence+Edits#ProfileExistenceEdits-Backingup/RestoringaProfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the error message is

> Rule not found: [repository=c-cppcheck, key=selfAssignment]
>
> Rule not found: [repository=c-cppcheck, key=returnTempPointer] ....

I assume that you try to check c++ code.

Are your c++ plugins of the same version?
Are your sonarqube-servers of the same version?

Compare server´s and plugins´ version of your export and import installation.

Comment: Please bear with me here since I am newbie in QA. What you mean by "Are your c++ plugins of the same version"? Do I need something else beside xml file I am trying to import? I tried to make xml backup from same version of sonarqube-server and import it back to the same sonarqube-server but it would give me Rule not found error so I don't think it is about sonarqube version.

Comment: look into both of your server installations. Find the folder /extensions/plugins and compare the name of the file of the c++ plugin

Comment: wait do I suppose to have anything in extensions/plugins? I am importing xml and sonar have UI so I can simply open xml to reconstruct quality profile right? Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Yes, but if your quality profile contains rules to check c++ code, you need the c++ plugin. Otherwise the rules cannot be found. And your error message sais: "Rule not found"

Comment: If you use your own plugin you should update your question and provide more relevant information.

Comment: so theoretically, if I have download a plugin from address below, I should be able to back up profile and restore without "Rule not found" error, correct? https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx/releases.

Comment: Okay let me see what I can do.

Comment: I suppose the missing rules are part of the c++ standard plugin, which you should download through the update center of your sonarqube server

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim for everything. You are right. I found some other open source plugin and now I can see more rules on a profile restored with xml-format but not all of them. I guess I will have to learn how to make plugin in one week or get lucky and stumble upon a plugin that perfectly fits backup profile. Again, Thank you!